# TestNG report shows 0 tests run in suite and 4 tests run in test

Tags: testng

I am trying to understand my testNG report and logs:
I have the following test suite:

```
<suite name="Data Creation" verbose="10" thread-count="16" data-provider-thread-count="16" parallel="&parallelType;">
  <test name="Data_Workflow_Tests" enabled="true">
    <parameter name="inputFile" value="createData.xml" />
    <classes>
        <class name="data.creation.test.NewDataCreationTests">
            <methods>
                <include name="test_data_creation_Workflows" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

And after running the suite, I get the following logs on the console:

===============================================
      Data_Workflow_Tests
      Tests run: 4, Failures: 4, Skips: 0
  ===============================================

===============================================
  Data Creation
  Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================

I do not understand why the suite shows "Total tests run: 0" when there have been 4 tests running.

Comment: What version of testNG are you using?

Comment: I am using version 6.8

Comment: Why tag <suite> is not closed? Did you provided whole file?

Comment: Just a typo, sorry about that